# Bounding the average slope of a convex function by an average of the slopes.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, reference-request, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

For a convex function $f$, I am interested in bounds of the form $$\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}\geq (1-\lambda)f'(y)+\lambda f'(x),\quad x<y.$$

For $\lambda=1$, this becomes true of any convex function $f$. On the other hand, for $\lambda= 0$, this only holds for a line. So I'm wondering which functions satisfy the above for small (but positive) values $\lambda$. For the parabola $f(x)=x^2$ this holds with $\lambda=1/2$. However, this also holds for functions like $f(x)=ax^2$ with $\lambda=1/2$ for any $a>0$, which tells me this $\lambda$ isn't a measure of curvature.

Does this quantity $\lambda$ have a name? Does this come up in the literature? (By $\lambda$ I mean the best possible $\lambda$.)

Comment: I think that $\lambda=1$ only holds for a line and $\lambda=0$ for every convex function. A minor fixable problem. In what sense do you mean the best possible $\lambda\,?$ The smallest/largest? Also: does $\lambda$ not depend on $x$ and $y\,?$ The latter seems to make it a bit hard to use as a measure of curvature.

Comment: @KurtG. Yes you are right, I had $x,y$ in the wrong order. By best possible I meant away from the universal $\lambda=1$. Yes, I suppose it would in general depend on the points, but I was wondering which convex functions satisfy such a condition uniformly over, say, a compact interval.

Comment: @KurtG. Also, I did not actually want this to be a measure of curvature, rather observed that this wasn't necessarily related to the curvature. Maybe it came out wrong when I said it the first time.

Comment: $LHS = f'(x) + \frac{1}{2}f''(x)(y - x) + \frac{1}{6}f'''(x) (y-x)^2 + \cdots$ 

$RHS = f'(x) + (1 - \lambda) f''(x) (y - x) + \frac{1}{2}(1-\lambda) f'''(x)(y - x)^2+\cdots$

If $f''(x) > 0$, then necessarily, $\frac{1}{2}\ge 1- \lambda$, that is, $\lambda \ge \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: I think it is a measure of curvature just that at this late moment of the day I don't see how useful it can be. Note that for every convex function that is differentiable we have
$$
f'(x)\le \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}\le f'(y)\,,\quad x<y\,.
$$
That $\lambda$ away from $1$ measures how close $f'(x)$ and $f'(y)$ are. When your inequality holds for  $\lambda=0$ then $f'(x)$ and $f'(y)$ are both below the fraction. But $f'(y)$ is always above it. So we must have a line. The traditional measure for curvature is the second derivative that tells us how much $f'$ is changing. Similar in spirit.

Comment: @KurtG. I see. I suppose I'm not trying to find a use for it, rather curious whether for every convex function we can find a non-trivial $\lambda$ satisfying the above. And if not, what the counterexamples would look like!

Comment: @KurtG. Indeed, the difference quotient is a convex combination of the two derivatives, but how do we know there is a single $\lambda<1$ that works for all $x,y$?

Comment: @KurtG. Cheers, I appreciate your time!

Comment: @KurtG. Ah, I think I can see it failing now. If the curve has a sharp corner, and if I pick $x$ on the left of the corner and let $y$ tend to the corner from the right, $\lambda\to 1$.